# Reading values from class dynamically leading to typescript error

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-class

I'm new and learning Typescript plus parallel implementing in my project. I have class of written in typescript as follows:

```
class Base {
  property1!: number
  property2!: string

  getValue(field: string) {
    const exists = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, field)
    const value = this[field]
    const isNotFunction = value !== 'function'
    return exists && isNotFunction && field !== 'id' && field !== 'type'
  }
}
```

Now `tsc` command is giving following error which is not much understandable to me. Please help.

```
src/models/base.ts - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Base'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Base'.

137     const value = this[field]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class `Base` has a predefined set of properties (`property1` and `property2`). Typescript is aware of this, so when you are trying to access a property of `Base` by a random string name (that `field: string`), it's telling you that you are probably doing something you shouldn't. Try changing it to `field: keyof Base` - this way you are ensuring that the the property actually exists on the object instance and you are getting a sensible typed result and not `any`